# MVC handle 401 response on any request

Tags: c#, http, session, model-view-controller, http-status-code-401

I have a C# MVC web application that will expire the user's session after 30 mins of being inactive, after that time if the user tries to do anything on the site it will be unauthorized as the token is expired. When I get that request from anywhere I want to be able to redirect the user to the homepage, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Either you can handle this at Controller level or Individual Action level. Use a custom attribute to redirect to your desired page(home page in your case) when you get unauthorized 401 request.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult(); // Try this but i'm not sure
          filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Unauthorized");
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            this.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }

}
```

And apply this at Controller or Action level

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```